# How do I create new shortcut on mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, shortcut

I want to create new shortcut for text command that I use often such as select * from 
I found an answer referring to main_menu.xml file but I didn't understand if I can create new shortcut or how can I use existed shortcut for my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Workbench allows you to save "Snippets" (SQL commands) copied from the main editing window - see here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-snippets.html

These appear in the tab on the right hand side & may be copied to the main editor or executed directly.

Comment: Thank you. After I'm adding a snippet, can I reach it by keyboard shortcut? If it's just for use in click, it doesn't answer my needs

Comment: I can't see a way to directly run a snippet from a keyboard shortcut. I notice that many of the shortcut commands are prefixed by "plugin:" - so it may be possible to create your own plugin & then assign a keyboard shortcut - though I cannot be sure on the latter. Some links for you : http://mysqlworkbench.org/workbench/doc/  ...  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-workbench/wb-extending.html ... http://mysqlworkbench.org/2009/03/python-scripting-in-workbench/